# Can't understand this Binary Search Tree (BST) algorithm for Insertion of value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am learning algorithms. For the BST Construction to insert a value in the BST, I came across this code. I am not that good at OOPS concept and can't figure out how currentnode.left = BST(value) and currentnode = currentnode.left works. If someone can help me understand this, it would be of great help.

```
class BST:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert(self, value):
        currentnode = self
        while True:
            if value < currentnode.value:
                if currentnode.left is None:
                   currentnode.left = BST(value)
                   break
                else:
                   currentnode = currentnode.left
            else:
                if currentnode.right is None:
                    currentnode.right = BST(value)
                    break
                else:
                    currentnode = currentnode.right
        return self
```

Comment: did you try to debug thrtough it? its a while loop, each node stores its value and a subtree of lower / higher values. Give a new value you start to look where to place it and descend if needed into the correct tree. if tree is empty, you create a new node. The code is not complete though, it does not handle reshuffling for one

Comment: Actually I don't understand how  the subtree is created at all. To understand I tried to print it but the output is only where the object is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the insert function, the currentnode has been assigned to self. Starting with the while loop, the parameter value is checked with currentnode's value. If it is small, the first condition is executed else second.

Now comes your doubt.
Let's say the first condition is being executed. If the currentnode's left value is none, then the code calls BST(value) i.e. the constructor is called which initiates a new node, which in turn becomes the currentnode's left child.
Else, if there is already a left child, that child becomes the currentnode and the while loop is iterated again and again until a suitable, position  is found.

Also, If this code seems complicated. You should refer this, just in case if it helps.

```
class Node: 
    def __init__(self,key): 
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = key 
  

def insert(root,node): 
    if root is None: 
        root = node 
    else: 
        if root.val < node.val: 
            if root.right is None: 
                root.right = node 
            else: 
                insert(root.right, node) 
        else: 
            if root.left is None: 
                root.left = node 
            else: 
                insert(root.left, node) 

#      5 
#    /    \ 
#   3       7
#   / \    / \ 
#  2   4  6   8 
r = Node(5) 
insert(r,Node(3)) 
insert(r,Node(2)) 
insert(r,Node(4)) 
insert(r,Node(7)) 
insert(r,Node(6)) 
insert(r,Node(8))
```

Comment: I understand the first half of what you said, that if the currentnode.left is none we call the constructor and initiates a new node but I don't understand how currentnode = currentnode.left works still. Its the same as self = self.left right? I just don't understand this. Can you help me clear this?

Comment: @YuvarajKrishna Yes, that is correct. The line basically tells you that the place where you want to insert your node is already filled with let's say node X, so it gives you X as your current node. Now, node X runs as your currentnode if node X's left value is empty the value is inserted there, if not the same procedure is done(left and right) until you get a perfect position.

Comment: Okayyyyy. Now I understand it much better. Thanks a lot @Bhavesh